To make DBT source.yml file dynamic
I want to set database name in source.yml file dynamically in DBT
Currently, I am executing it via AzureADO
current source file is
version: 2

sources:
  - name: source
    database: db1

I want to make this database name dynamic.
I tried using target but since it use profile.yml which is statis in repository, its not possible
I tried using env variables as well
- script: |
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=database_name]PREPROD"
              displayName: 'Set DB Variables'
version: 2

sources:
  - name: src_1
    database: "{{ env_var('database_name') }}"

but gets error as  Env var required but not provided

There's nothing wrong with your syntax. You don't have the env variable properly set up in your env, which is exactly what the error message is telling you. If you're running locally, make sure you're exporting database_name (case sensitive). If you're running this in DBT Cloud, you need to add the variable to Deploy -> Environments -> Environment Variables

We are working with DBT core currently.

Hi @RajasPatil, can the Replace Tokens task in my answer help you set database name in source.yml file dynamically? Please let me know if you need more help about the issue.

You can use the Replace Tokens task to replace the database name in source.yml file dynamically.
Use the Token pattern #{database_name}# in source.yml:
version: 2

sources:
  - name: source
    database: #{database_name}#

Set the variable in the pipeline variables section:
variables: 
  - name: database_name
    value: testname

steps:
- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/your file folder'
    sources: 'source.yml'

Or set the variable in a script in the pipeline:
steps:
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=database_name]testname"
  displayName: 'Set DB Variables'
- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/your file folder'
    sources: 'source.yml'

It will replace the #{database_name}# with the variable you set in the pipeline.

You can also use the parameters in the pipeline. When the pipeline runs, you can select the database_name.
Sample pipeline yaml:
parameters:
- name: database_name
  values:
  - database_name1
  - database_name2
  - database_name3
  default: database_name1

variables: 
  - name: database_name
    value: ${{ parameters.database_name }}

steps:
- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/your file folder'
    sources: 'source.yml'


